# Correct strategy for auth in an API

Tags: security, oauth, jwt, graphql, openid-connect

I want to design a GraphQL API. This API would be used by some browser apps and also open to be used directly for people that want to create their own scripts/generate reports etc. The API would rely on a third party app supporting Oauth Openid Connect (okta) for user and role management. It would be written in Django.

Because JWT is a recommended way of protecting GraphQL APIs and also because OIDC uses JWT tokens. I thought of a simple way, where the API would simply accept the JWT tokens issued by okta. This works, but I see a lot of latency when API is asking okta validate the token (this latency might be smaller in production, because I'm testing on a free trial auth0 instead of production okta). So I think that maybe my API should issue its own JWT tokens. I can think of three strategies here:

1. Leave it as is – only use the OIDC JWTs.
2. Introduce a login mutation or a login REST endpoint, that would accept OIDC above and issue JWTs that can be used for all other operations.
3. As above, but also allow the direct use of okta's JWTs (I'm not sure if I can implement it with Django's auth system, so that if a token is recognised, the OIDC is not called).

Which of these three is the correct (and maybe intended by the OIDC designers) way to protect my API?

Comment: Comparing Auth0 (Trial) and Okta performances seems abit off? Generally, I suggest only use the OIDC. Using your own or any proprietary authentication is a vendor lock-in and may prevent integration with others.

Comment: I am using only OIDC. I don't use any features that are specific to okta or auth0. Only OIDC protocol, they both implement.

Comment: JWT token doesn't need to be validated by Okta (generally by IdP). You just need to get used public key (it can be found as jwks url in discovery response) and then can you can verify signatures without any IdP call. IMHO you can get 2-4k validations/sec easily.

Comment: Thanks. This means I need to take a closer look on how the django plugin handles it. Maybe it is misconfigured and doesn't cache the keys after downloading them. Or maybe it tries to retrieve the user data for every call. I believe, this comment could be an answer I am looking for.

Comment: OK. Now I see that mozilla_django_oidc when it is used with 'jwks-endpoint' configured will redownload the keys for every check. After this it will always get the user info, even if the user is already in the database. This is the root of the latency. If you don't mind, please write the information you gave me as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT token doesn't need to be validated by Okta (generally by IdP). You just need to get used public key (it can be found as jwks url in discovery response) and then can you can verify signatures without any IdP call.

IMHO you can get 2-4k validations/sec easily.

Comment: Thanks again. I opened a ticket for mozilla-django-oidc https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-django-oidc/issues/324 I hope my idea gets approved and I can merge my fix.

Comment: I'm not sure about your setup, but I would recommend https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper - it can be single static binary, which will act as authentication/authorization proxy in front of GraphQL endpoint. It can be used with any OIDC IdP (Okta, Google, Keycloak, ....)